# The use of never

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

would somebody help me to correct this sentence:
"I thought being all alone was never this ugly" 
Is it grammatically correct? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your question, but without more specifics about your concerns with "never" it sounds a bit like a proofreading request.  Help us understand by including more details on your thinking and whatever research you've already done on the issue.  "I'm worried that _never_ doesn't work here because…" or "These two sources [here] and [there] seem to disagree because it sounds to me like they're saying…"

Answer (score 1):

> "I thought being all alone was never this ugly"

It is grammatical but it isn't normal usage.

I suggest, "I never thought being alone was this ugly."